# Get Parent Schema Property for Validation with Mongoose and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say that I have a nested Schema (invitation) in another schema (item) and when trying to save an invitation object, I want to check if the parent property 'enabled' from the item schema is set to true or false before allowing the person to save the invite object to the invitations array. Obviously, this.enabled doesn't work as it's trying to get it off of the invitationSchema, which doesn't exist. How would one get the 'enabled' property on the parent schema to validate?

Any thoughts? Thanks for any help!

```
var validateType = function(v) {
    if (v === 'whateverCheck') {
       return this.enabled || false; <== this doesn't work
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};

var invitationSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    type: {
        type: String,
        validate: [validateType, 'error message.']
    }
 });

var itemSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    enabled: {type: Boolean}, <== trying to access this here
    invitations: { type: [ invitationSchema ] },
});

var ItemModel = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema, 'items');
var InvitationModel = mongoose.model('Invitation', invitationSchema);
```

Answer (score 6):

The parent of an embedded document is accessible from an embedded doc model instance by calling `instance.parent();`. So you can do this from any Mongoose middleware like a validator or a hook.

In your case you can do :

```
var validateType = function(v) {
    if (v === 'whateverCheck') {
       return this.parent().enabled || false; // <== this does work
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};
```